# How to extend my "locked" root partition ? - Ubuntu 17

Tags: gparted, root

As shown in screenshot, I want to collect all unallocated memory to one partition and extend root to it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: To make any changes to EXT4 or SWAP partitions, you'll need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Your root partition looks fine. It's sda5/6/7 that need the help. And... since you're only single booting, NTFS is not the best choice for your data partitions.

Comment: @AndroidDev It is possible... but I'm initially recommending something else to zLegend.

Comment: @heynnema Well I know that it's possible on Windows with NTFS, but I don't know about EXT4

Comment: @heynnema After booting from ubuntu live, should I be able to proceed extending without any troubles ?

Comment: @AndroidDev Is it impossible because of ntfs or what else ?

Comment: All you need to do is create a Live DVD/USB of Gpart & boot, because of which your root drive won't be locked anymore. Once you have successfully booted using Gpart, you can easily increase/decrease disk space of any partition in your hard drive. 

You may have a look at my tutorial [link](http://www.evagabond.me/2014/12/using-gparted-partition-editor-in.html)

Comment: Please clarify what/why you want the end result to be. Why do you want to extend root when it has plenty of room? Aren't you concerned that your 3 NTFS partitions show as full? Are you considering changing from NTFS to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've solved this by resizing the root partition from booting from Ubuntu usb stick, but make sure first that the unallocated memory are collected and placed just after the root partition.